# Could javascript be causing multiple links to disappear

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal

I am trying to create a website using Drupal 7 with a theme installed. On the front page when I try to put in more than one linked image: e.g.

```
<a href='http://www.hp.com/UK' title='HP UK' target='_blank'>  <img class="fronticon" src='sites/all/themes/corporate/images/fronticons/partnerlogo.jpg' alt='HP Business Partner logo'> </a>
<a href='http://www.hp.com/UK' title='HP UK' target='_blank'>  <img class="fronticon" src='sites/all/themes/corporate/images/fronticons/partnerlogo.jpg' alt='HP Business Partner logo'> </a>
```

then no links appear. However, if I just put one link, the image appears and works as a link. I posted about this on Drupal Answers and the only respondant thought that this might be being caused by css/javascript. The front page has a jQuery slider on it. When I put the same bit of html on other pages that don't have the slider it works ok. So I am wondering if the jQuery code is causing the issue. Here is the code from the slider.js file that is part of the theme:

```
jQuery(function(){
  jQuery('#slides').slides({
    play: 5000,
    pause: 2500,
    hoverPause: true 
  });
});

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery("#slides").hover(function() {
    jQuery(".slides_nav").css("display", "block");
  },
  function() {
    jQuery(".slides_nav").css("display", "none");
  });
});
```

There is also a file called slides.min.jquery.js which consists of one long line of code:

```
(function(a){a.fn.slides=function(b){return b=a.extend({},a.fn.slides.option,b),this.each(function(){function w(g,h,i){if(!p&&o){p=!0,b.animationStart(n+1);switch(g){case"next":l=n,k=n+1,k=e===k?0:k,r=f*2,g=-f*2,n=k;break;case"prev":l=n,k=n-1,k=k===-1?e-1:k,r=0,g=0,n=k;break;case"pagination":k=parseInt(i,10),l=a("."+b.paginationClass+" li."+b.currentClass+" a",c).attr("href").match("[^#/]+$"),k>l?(r=f*2,g=-f*2):(r=0,g=0),n=k}h==="fade"?b.crossfade?d.children(":eq("+k+")",c).css({zIndex:10}).fadeIn(b.fadeSpeed,b.fadeEasing,function(){b.autoHeight?d.animate({height:d.children(":eq("+k+")",c).outerHeight()},b.autoHeightSpeed,function(){d.children(":eq("+l+")",c).css({display:"none",zIndex:0}),d.children(":eq("+k+")",c).css({zIndex:0}),b.animationComplete(k+1),p=!1}):(d.children(":eq("+l+")",c).css({display:"none",zIndex:0}),d.children(":eq("+k+")",c).css({zIndex:0}),b.animationComplete(k+1),p=!1)}):d.children(":eq("+l+")",c).fadeOut(b.fadeSpeed,b.fadeEasing,function(){b.autoHeight?d.animate({height:d.children(":eq("+k+")",c).outerHeight()},b.autoHeightSpeed,function(){d.children(":eq("+k+")",c).fadeIn(b.fadeSpeed,b.fadeEasing)}):d.children(":eq("+k+")",c).fadeIn(b.fadeSpeed,b.fadeEasing,function(){a.browser.msie&&a(this).get(0).style.removeAttribute("filter")}),b.animationComplete(k+1),p=!1}):(d.children(":eq("+k+")").css({left:r,display:"block"}),b.autoHeight?d.animate({left:g,height:d.children(":eq("+k+")").outerHeight()},b.slideSpeed,b.slideEasing,function(){d.css({left:-f}),d.children(":eq("+k+")").css({left:f,zIndex:5}),d.children(":eq("+l+")").css({left:f,display:"none",zIndex:0}),b.animationComplete(k+1),p=!1}):d.animate({left:g},b.slideSpeed,b.slideEasing,function(){d.css({left:-f}),d.children(":eq("+k+")").css({left:f,zIndex:5}),d.children(":eq("+l+")").css({left:f,display:"none",zIndex:0}),b.animationComplete(k+1),p=!1})),b.pagination&&(a("."+b.paginationClass+" li."+b.currentClass,c).removeClass(b.currentClass),a("."+b.paginationClass+" li:eq("+k+")",c).addClass(b.currentClass))}}function x(){clearInterval(c.data("interval"))}function y(){b.pause?(clearTimeout(c.data("pause")),clearInterval(c.data("interval")),u=setTimeout(function(){clearTimeout(c.data("pause")),v=setInterval(function(){w("next",i)},b.play),c.data("interval",v)},b.pause),c.data("pause",u)):x()}a("."+b.container,a(this)).children().wrapAll('<div class="slides_control"/>');var c=a(this),d=a(".slides_control",c),e=d.children().size(),f=d.children().outerWidth(),g=d.children().outerHeight(),h=b.start-1,i=b.effect.indexOf(",")<0?b.effect:b.effect.replace(" ","").split(",")[0],j=b.effect.indexOf(",")<0?i:b.effect.replace(" ","").split(",")[1],k=0,l=0,m=0,n=0,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v;if(e<2)return a("."+b.container,a(this)).fadeIn(b.fadeSpeed,b.fadeEasing,function(){o=!0,b.slidesLoaded()}),a("."+b.next+", ."+b.prev).fadeOut(0),!1;if(e<2)return;h<0&&(h=0),h>e&&(h=e-1),b.start&&(n=h),b.randomize&&d.randomize(),a("."+b.container,c).css({overflow:"hidden",position:"relative"}),d.children().css({position:"absolute",top:0,left:d.children().outerWidth(),zIndex:0,display:"none"}),d.css({position:"relative",width:f*3,height:g,left:-f}),a("."+b.container,c).css({display:"block"}),b.autoHeight&&(d.children().css({height:"auto"}),d.animate({height:d.children(":eq("+h+")").outerHeight()},b.autoHeightSpeed));if(b.preload&&d.find("img:eq("+h+")").length){a("."+b.container,c).css({background:"url("+b.preloadImage+") no-repeat 50% 50%"});var z=d.find("img:eq("+h+")").attr("src")+"?"+(new Date).getTime();a("img",c).parent().attr("class")!="slides_control"?t=d.children(":eq(0)")[0].tagName.toLowerCase():t=d.find("img:eq("+h+")"),d.find("img:eq("+h+")").attr("src",z).load(function(){d.find(t+":eq("+h+")").fadeIn(b.fadeSpeed,b.fadeEasing,function(){a(this).css({zIndex:5}),a("."+b.container,c).css({background:""}),o=!0,b.slidesLoaded()})})}else d.children(":eq("+h+")").fadeIn(b.fadeSpeed,b.fadeEasing,function(){o=!0,b.slidesLoaded()});b.bigTarget&&(d.children().css({cursor:"pointer"}),d.children().click(function(){return w("next",i),!1})),b.hoverPause&&b.play&&(d.bind("mouseover",function(){x()}),d.bind("mouseleave",function(){y()})),b.generateNextPrev&&(a("."+b.container,c).after('<a href="#" class="'+b.prev+'">Prev</a>'),a("."+b.prev,c).after('<a href="#" class="'+b.next+'">Next</a>')),a("."+b.next,c).click(function(a){a.preventDefault(),b.play&&y(),w("next",i)}),a("."+b.prev,c).click(function(a){a.preventDefault(),b.play&&y(),w("prev",i)}),b.generatePagination?(b.prependPagination?c.prepend("<ul class="+b.paginationClass+"></ul>"):c.append("<ul class="+b.paginationClass+"></ul>"),d.children().each(function(){a("."+b.paginationClass,c).append('<li><a href="#'+m+'">'+(m+1)+"</a></li>"),m++})):a("."+b.paginationClass+" li a",c).each(function(){a(this).attr("href","#"+m),m++}),a("."+b.paginationClass+" li:eq("+h+")",c).addClass(b.currentClass),a("."+b.paginationClass+" li a",c).click(function(){return b.play&&y(),q=a(this).attr("href").match("[^#/]+$"),n!=q&&w("pagination",j,q),!1}),a("a.link",c).click(function(){return b.play&&y(),q=a(this).attr("href").match("[^#/]+$")-1,n!=q&&w("pagination",j,q),!1}),b.play&&(v=setInterval(function(){w("next",i)},b.play),c.data("interval",v))})},a.fn.slides.option={preload:!1,preloadImage:"/img/loading.gif",container:"slides_container",generateNextPrev:!1,next:"next",prev:"prev",pagination:!0,generatePagination:!0,prependPagination:!1,paginationClass:"pagination",currentClass:"current",fadeSpeed:350,fadeEasing:"",slideSpeed:350,slideEasing:"",start:1,effect:"slide",crossfade:!1,randomize:!1,play:0,pause:0,hoverPause:!1,autoHeight:!1,autoHeightSpeed:350,bigTarget:!1,animationStart:function(){},animationComplete:function(){},slidesLoaded:function(){}},a.fn.randomize=function(b){function c(){return Math.round(Math.random())-.5}return a(this).each(function(){var d=a(this),e=d.children(),f=e.length;if(f>1){e.hide();var g=[];for(i=0;i<f;i++)g[g.length]=i;g=g.sort(c),a.each(g,function(a,c){var f=e.eq(c),g=f.clone(!0);g.show().appendTo(d),b!==undefined&&b(f,g),f.remove()})}})}})(jQuery)
```

Is anyone able to tell me if the problem is being caused by anything in here? As you may have guessed by now I don't know much about Javascript/jQuery.

Comment: Why don't use only one <a> with the two <imgs> inside it?

Comment: Because I want each image to have it's own, different link.

Comment: I would remove the <a> and do something like this: _http://jsfiddle.net/na95y19y/_ ... Maybe it can work to you

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Where would I put the javascript - just in the page header?

Comment: After your existing code, look here: _http://jsfiddle.net/na95y19y/1/_

Comment: I've added your code and changed the <img> tag as you suggest. The images both appear but the links don't work.

Comment: ...and if I add more than two <img> tags the images all disappear again.

Comment: I saw the site now.. you are using bootstrap, maybe this problem is caused cause the area is responsive. Have you tried to resize the page? If it isn't a jquery problem, I think I can't help

Comment: How did you find my site? Is it the one on azure websites? I didn't know the theme used bootstrap. In any case the problem doesn't occur on other pages, which are presumably equally responsive.

Comment: I assumed that you are working in some page inside _http://www.hp.com/UK_

Comment: No. btw I checked and the theme I am using is not responsive.